# Как установить последний virtualenv в Ubuntu12.04?

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv

В Ubuntu 12.04 по умолчанию ставится virtualenv 1.7.1.2. Мне не удается поставить последние версии. Удалил его, и ставлю заново. Если ставлю через pip:

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
```

Пишет об успешной установке последней версии:

```
Downloading/unpacking virtualenv
  Downloading virtualenv-13.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.7MB): 1.7MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
Successfully installed virtualenv
Cleaning up...
```

Проверяю:

```
virtualenv --version
```

Выдает:

```
bash: /usr/bin/virtualenv: Нет такого файла или каталога
```

Если ставлю так:

```
sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
```

То естественно опять ставится virtualnv 1.7.1.2

Мне собственно это нужно для создания окружения под Python 3.4 в Ubuntu 12.04. А штатный virtualenv отказывается создавать окружение с этой версией Питона

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не используйте `sudo pip` для установки Питон пакетов в системные папки. Системные пакеты на Ubuntu должны управляться соответствующим менеджером пакетов, например, через `apt-get` клиент командой строки. Важные системные утилиты могут зависеть от системного python, поэтому они могут перестать работать, если вы сломаете вашу инсталляцию Питона.

Для вашего пользователя можно поставить, используя `--user` опцию:

```
$ python3.4 -m pip install --user virtualenv -U
```

Убедитесь, что `~/.local/bin` папка в пути (`$PATH`) находится.

Можно вообще без установки обойтись: [просто скачайте `virtualenv` архив и запустите `virtualenv.py` из него, используя нужную версию питона, чтобы создать новое окружение](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html).

Comment: Спасибо большое. Удалось поставить.