# pip install падает с AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HTTPMessage'

Tags: python, ubuntu

Последнее обновление системы (Ubuntu 15.10) частично убило pip, попытка установить любой пакет крашится с ошибкой:

```
$ sudo pip install virtualenv
Downloading/unpacking virtualenv
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 304, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1178, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 194, in find_requirement
    page = self._get_page(main_index_url, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_page
    session=self.session,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 670, in get_page
    resp = session.get(url, headers={"Accept": "text/html"})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 477, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 237, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 557, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 388, in _make_request
    assert_header_parsing(httplib_response.msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/util/response.py", line 49, in assert_header_parsing
    if not isinstance(headers, httplib.HTTPMessage):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HTTPMessage'
```

Сломал голову - не могу понять в чем проблема и как её устранить.

Переустанавливать `python-pip` и `python-urllib3` пробовал.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А так:

```
sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
```

?

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Не понял только в чем была проблема.

Comment: @PavelKarateev: [не используйте `sudo pip` на Ubuntu](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/475926/23044)